# Why does my ternary operator give a different result to an if else?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ternary-operator, game-development

The problem I am having is I am trying to use ternary operators over if else for smaller code but when using it in my case it is returning a different result than if I use an if else.

The problem code is below;

If Else

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(jn["LARM"].Value))
            pm.ItemLeftArm = null;
        else
            pm.ItemLeftArm = jn["LARM"];
```

Ternary

```
pm.ItemLeftArm = string.IsNullOrEmpty(jn["LARM"].Value) ? null : jn["LARM"];
```

The jn["LARM"] is a json node from simpleJSON and it is either a number e.g. "0" or nothing e.g. "".

It returns null form the if else but it returns the jn object which transforms from "" into 0.

Im not sure why Im getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok, the problem must be in the JSON. Have you tried logging the `jn["LARM"].Value` just before the terniary operator in order to be sure that the value is null/empty or not?

BTW, why are you using simpleJSON instead of the new Unity integrated JsonUtility?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,
The if statement return true and sets the pm.ItemLeftArm to true but replaced with the ternary operator returns false and sets the pm.ItemLeftArm to jn["LARM"]. There is no difference with the if and ternary but they give different results and I'm not sure why.

I can work around it but I was just wondering why this might happen?

Comment: I'll do a few printouts tonight when I finish work just to trace what the issues could be and post them